# How to schedule data insertion from dbf to SQL Server on 64-bit Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-express, scheduler, dbf

I am working on a Windows Server 2012 64-bit. I want to be able to import data from a `.dbf` file into a SQL Server table. I used the import wizard and it worked correctly. However, I have SQL Server Express and can't schedule this insertion.

Is there another way to schedule the insertion of the `.dbf` data to the SQL Server tables, without the use of the SSIS package loader?

**Update**

I ended up using Python and writing a script to import from XML. However, I believe the answer by @Oleg was the most accurate, given the circumstances.

Thank you all!

Comment: You can always write a little C# wrapper that will call the SSIS package, and then schedule that wrapper (using Windows "Scheduled Tasks") to be executed on a particular schedule

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping there would be another way, but I think this the only way to do it. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use DBF Commander Pro for this task:

1. Create command line for your insertion - choose 'File -> Export to DBMS'. Specify transfer options in the window appears, then copy the command line from the bottom of the window:
   [image: export DBF to database]
2. Create text .BAT file and insert the copied command line, e.g.:

   "c:\Program Files\DBFCommander\DBFCommander.exe" -edb "D:\Data\customer.dbf" customer_table "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=user1;Initial Catalog=test_db;Data Source=test_server"
3. Make a schedule using Windows Scheduler that will execute this .BAT file.

Additional info that may be useful for you:

[Using DBF in batch mode](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-command-line.html)
[Export DBF file to SQL database](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the next approach:

1. Create C# script which will use the `OleDbConnection` (to fetch) and `SqlConnection` (to upload) objects to import data from the `.DBF` file to SQL Server database table.
2. By using `LinqPad`, LinqPad command-line utility (`lprun.exe`) and windows `Scheduled Task` service automate the execution of the mentioned script file

---

Useful links:

[How to get data from DBF file using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/559478/ImportingplusaplusDBFplusfileplusintoplusC)

[How to load data into datadase using C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient)

[About LINQPad command-line utility](http://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is create a SQL linked server an ODBC that is pointing at the DBF. Use Windows scheduler to call SQLCMD.EXE to run some SQL to copy the data in.